# How to return a group of loop values as a single string

Tags: python, loops, for-loop, return

I'm new to coding, I started to learn python last month. My friend give me this problem and I'm stuck

```
def gordon(a):
    x = a.split()
    result = " "
    for y in x:
        c = " ".join((y.upper().replace("A", "@").replace("E", "*").replace("I", "*").replace("O", "*").replace("U", "*"))) + "!!!!"
        


gordon('What feck damn cake')
```

I want to return a value of

```
W H @ T!!!! F * C K!!!!  D @ M N!!!! C @ K *!!!!
```

what I'm getting this insteead and I can't find a way to fix it

```
W H @ T!!!!
F * C K!!!!
D @ M N!!!!
C @ K *!!!!
```

Comment: You don't use `result` anywhere or print anything. Please create a [mcve].

Comment: indeed, the code above does not print or return anything, it's not possible that it gives the output you mentioned.

Answer (score 0):

you must be printing c in the loop. try c+=, instead of just c =
print c outside the loop

Answer (score 0):

```py
def gordon(a):
    x = a.split()
    result = []
    for y in x:
        result.append(
            y
                .upper()
                .replace("A", "@")
                .replace("E", "*")
                .replace("I", "*")
                .replace("O", "*")
                .replace("U", "*")
                + "!!!!"
        )

    return " ".join(result)
        


gordon('What feck damn cake')
```

Answer (score 0):

To give you very close answer to your work, here is the small fixed to your code but it'll lead to extra space in the end.

```
def gordon(a):
    x = a.split()
    result = ""
    for y in x:
        result += " ".join((y.upper().replace("A", "@").replace("E", "*").replace("I", "*").replace("O", "*").replace("U", "*"))) + "!!!! "
    print(result)


gordon('What feck damn cake')
```

---

For a better one, we should use "result" as array to collect each "c" and join those all c with a space(" ").

```
def gordon(a):
    x = a.split()
    result = []
    for y in x:
        c = " ".join((y.upper().replace("A", "@").replace("E", "*").replace("I", "*").replace("O", "*").replace("U", "*"))) + "!!!!"
        result.append(c)
    print(" ".join(result))

gordon('What feck damn cake')
```